# Viewing jasper reports on client side in vaadin application

Tags: java, applet, jasper-reports, vaadin

I am working on a vaadin application in which I have to use JasperReports. Now what I want is to whenever a report is generated, it should be viewed in JasperViewer. But problem is that the JasperViewer runs only on server side but not on client side, and i want something which I can use to view report at client side. Is there any way for this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the JasperViewer can be run on client side...

However an alternative is to store the file name and when user select the view report option you can then read this file from your local system and show it..It will be equivalent to showing a .pdf file on a browser...

You can also store the file in different formats which are offered by Jasper...